# elements gets wrap to next line when Overflow

Tags: css, reactjs

I want to show a list of items(like a span with text in it and tooltip) wrapped to next line if overflow like below. Items are separated by comma and when you hover on the text, it shows the item's full name. I am trying to use flexbox with flex-wrap, but there are more spaces between each item which is not I want. In addition, I prefer not to give a max-width for each item if possible. Is there a good way to achieve the goal?

mockup:

```
Item1, Item2, Item333, Item4,
Item5, Item6
```

Code:

```
<div className={container}>
    {items.map((item, index) => <span title={item.fullName}>{`${item.name}{index !== items.length ? ', ' : ''}`}</span>)}
</div>
```

Comment: Don't really need flex here unless there's other requirements. Instead maybe just assign `display: inline-block; max-width: 123px;` to your `span` elements since they're `inline` by default. Then you've got your wrapping and the max width.

Comment: Can you clarify your issue, without any style, it wraps : https://jsfiddle.net/2spu07v1/

Comment: Ah, I just realized I was adding some styles to it and make it not wrapped. Thanks!